# Manga with a male main character who goes to a dwarven blacksmith village

Tags: story-identification, manga

When he meets the head of the village, he has to duck into the meeting room, and gives them barrels of drink. The dwarven village contains three tribes which share a big magic sword. He then breaks it and remakes it for them. This is all I can remember from the manga. Also, there is a stone giant chained up underwater that the dwarves watch over. I think it's in the same one.

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: It was Black & white

Comment: He fixes the sword - I assume this means he's a blacksmith himself. Or if not, does he fix the sword in some other way? Alchemy? Magic? A repair skill? Is this something that happens early on in the manga (e.g. first 5 chapters or so) or later? Just to check - the main character is not an elf, right?